# FreeBSD 8.4 pkgdb fails after upgrade to Ruby 1.9

Tags: package-management, freebsd, ruby

I just upgrade Ruby 1.8 to Ruby 1.9. After the upgrade I followed the instructions in the UPDATING file located in `/usr/ports`. I issued the following two commands:

```
portmaster -o lang/ruby19 lang/ruby18
portmaster -R -r ruby-1.9
```

When I issue a `pkgdb` I get the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `required cannot load such file -- pkgtools (LoadError)

Short of restoring the system to the backup before the upgrade, can someone suggest an alternate solution?

Comment: I would follow the suggestion of these guys, and let pkgdb alone, since it is not really user by `portmaster` - https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=43847

Deinstall `ports-mgmt/portupgrade` and `rb-bdb` port and your are good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed the instructions and all is well. I must admit, I've never used portupgrade and have been astounded at how much easier it properly upgrades software. I guess when you start with earlier releases, in my case version 5 of FreeBSD, you tend to use scripts you've developed over the years for system maintenance. Portupgrade is an incredible improvement over scouring logs for missing or incorrectly upgraded prior dependencies, not to mention the requirement to 'make de-install', followed by 'make re-install'.

Comment: On my netbook, i tend to use pkgng (`pkg install ...`) since i dont have enough "horsepower" to compile everything. lol. Glad it worked.